# Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

Here's the full error message:

> Searchkick::InvalidQueryError:         Searchkick::InvalidQueryError:
>   [400]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata
>   is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on
>   [foo_name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting
>   the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant
>   memory."}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all
>   shards
>   failed","phase":"query","grouped":true,"failed_shards":[{"shard":0,"index":"foos_test","node":"k0yYkVnIQzaXbvpAG_rKgw","reason":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata
>   is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on
>   [foo_name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting
>   the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant
>   memory."}}],"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Fielddata
>   is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on
>   [foo_name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting
>   the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant
>   memory."}},"status":400}

I get this error (this error only shows in minitest) when I add the code below in index action:

```
order: {foo_name: :asc}
```

Here's my full index code:

```
def index
  query = params[:q].presence || "*"
  @foos = Foo.search(
    query,
    page: params[:page], per_page: 25,
    order: {foo_name: :asc}
    )
  end
end
```

I'm using Searchkick.

Answer (score 2):

This was a nasty one; we were fortunate to stumble on the solution. I assume your model looks something like this:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :foo_name

  searchkick # some settings

  def search_data
    { foo_name: foo_name }
  end
end
```

What you need to do is define a foo_name_sort field with the same value as foo_name, but set to filterable:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :foo_name

  searchkick # some settings,
             filterable [:foo_name_sort]

  def search_data
    { foo_name: foo_name,
      foo_name_sort: foo_name }
  end
end
```

And then to search:

```
@foos = Foo.search(
  query,
  page: params[:page], per_page: 25,
  order: {foo_name_sort: :asc}
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def index
  query = params[:q].presence || "*"
  @foos = Foo.search(
    query,
    page: params[:page], per_page: 25,
    aggs: {foo_name: {order: {"_term" => "asc"}}}
   )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your order like this:

```
order: {'foo_name.keyword' => 'asc'}
```